# move row to another sheet based on cell value google sheets - issue with code

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have hit the wall and can't pass it.

I have been using a code to move and compare data in the spreadsheet.

After testing i tried to move code to spreadsheet where i want this code work but am having a problem.

I have tried to remove a trigger for script on test sheet and there i started to having issues as well. Any ideas why that might be?. Code was working fine for a about week.

```js
function Move_new_Data(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Form responses 5")
  var tin = ss.getSheetByName("IN")
  var tout = ss.getSheetByName("OUT")
  var trsh = ss.getSheetByName("TRUE( Archive )")
  var mas = ss.getSheetByName("FR Check LIST")

  var vls = e.values;

  

  if (vls[2] == "IN"){
    
    
    var dt = tout.getDataRange().getValues();
    var dt2 = mas.getDataRange().getValues();
    var st = false;
    var st2 = false;
    for (var i =0;i<dt.length;i++){
      if(dt[i][2] == vls[1] && dt[i][3] == vls[3]){
        trsh.appendRow([null,vls[1],vls[3],vls[3],dt[i][0],vls[0],"TRUE"])
        tout.deleteRow(i+1)
        st = true;

        for (var j =0;j<dt2.length;j++){
          if(dt2[j][1] == vls[1]){
            mas.deleteRow(j+1);
            break;
          }
        }
        break;
      }

      else if(dt[i][2] == vls[1]){
        for (var j =0;j<dt2.length;j++){
          if(dt2[j][1] == vls[1]){
            mas.getRange(j+1,4).setValue(vls[3])
            //mas.getRange(4,j+1).setValue(vls[3])
            st2 = true;
            break;
            
          }
        }
      }
    }

    

    if (st == false){
      tin.appendRow([vls[0],vls[2],vls[1],vls[3]])
      
      if(st2 == false){
        var n = mas.getRange("B2:B").getValues().filter(String).length+2;
        mas.getRange(n,1,1,4).setValues([[null,vls[1],null,vls[3]]])
      }
      
    }

    sh.deleteRow(sh.getLastRow())
  }

   else if (vls[2] == "OUT"){
    
    
    var dt = tin.getDataRange().getValues();
    var dt2 = mas.getDataRange().getValues();
    var st = false;
    var st2 = false;
    for (var i =0;i<dt.length;i++){
      if(dt[i][2] == vls[1] && dt[i][3] == vls[3]){
        trsh.appendRow([null,vls[1],vls[3],vls[3],dt[i][0],vls[0],"TRUE"])
        tin.deleteRow(i+1)
        st = true;

        for (var j =0;j<dt2.length;j++){
          if(dt2[j][1] == vls[1]){
            mas.deleteRow(j+1);
            break;
          }
        }
        break;
      }

      else if(dt[i][2] == vls[1]){
        for (var j =0;j<dt2.length;j++){
          if(dt2[j][1] == vls[1]){
            mas.getRange(j+1,3).setValue(vls[3])
            //mas.getRange(4,j+1).setValue(vls[3])
            st2 = true;
            break;
            
          }
        }
      }
    }

    

    if (st == false){
      tout.appendRow([vls[0],vls[2],vls[1],vls[3]])
      
      if (st2 == false){
        var n = mas.getRange("B2:B").getValues().filter(String).length+2;
        mas.getRange(n,1,1,4).setValues([[null,vls[1],vls[3],null]])
      }
      
    }

    sh.deleteRow(sh.getLastRow())
  }
 
}
```

Scripts is being trigger when google form is submitted

Here how trigger is set: [image: Trigger]

Any ideas.

Looking at Executions history all have been completed with no issue. Not sure why is not working anymore.

Comment: Your script appears to be appending rows to, and deleting rows from, multiple sheet tabs everytime it's triggered. Are there no rows being appended to or deleted from any of the sheets? It would be best if you could also be able to share a [sample sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/138382/how-to-share-a-google-sheets-demo-spreadsheet/138383#138383) showing your expected input from the form responses.

Comment: Data from Form Responses 4 should be move to named sheets and row from responses should be removed. As data is moved to IN or OUT 2nd part of code should copy data to FR Check List where data will be comapre and if matching will be moved to history. 

That's short explanation for what i was using this script.

As mentioned before script worked but stopped working on Test sheet and Original ( never started working). There was no changes in script while duplicating document and changing to Usable version ( not testing one )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manage to figure the issue out.
I will edit this answer with solution for my code, it might be helpful for someone in the future.

UPDATE:

Here what fixed the issue for me.

```html
  var vls1 = e.values;

  var vls = [vls1[0],vls1[2],vls1[1],vls1[3]]

  Logger.log(vls)
```

Hope that will help someone too.

Comment: Hi RyuukuS, Actually this is not an answer. I believe you are not able to add comments yet but you can update your question instead of this. Happy coding!